# BERT Classification fine tuning for Q & A

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, corpus-linguistics

I want to fine-tune BERT for Q & A in a different way than the SQuAD mission:

I have pairs of (question, answer)

Part of them are the correct answer (Label - 1)

Part of them are the incorrect answer (Label - 0)

I want to fine-tune BERT to learn the classification mission: Given a pair of (q, a), predict if a is a correct answer for q.

What is the best way to do it?
Which model should I use?

What is this mission?

It's not a classic classification because the run_classifier demands only the text and the label, and I have the answer as well.

It's also not classic q&a like SQuAD...

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: I wonder if the model has been well trained how would you use it (to do reference)? Will you input the question and a random(correct or incorrect) answer?

Comment: The input would be a question, and the output should be the most similar (Qi, Ai) pair